# Is there a way to tell if a method has a call path to another method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Say I have a very high level method A and I just want to know if there is a some way down the call stack a reference to method B but don't know (yet) the input data required to actually hit method B. Is there a quick way of determining this without debugging or jumping through all the possible call stacks?

Comment: You can use reflection techniques similar to those in Reflector or dotPeek. They are non-trivial though. There is no convenient way.

Comment: I would probably use NDepend to accomplish this.

Comment: In the general sense, no. In a specific scenario, depends on the scenario. If you have service resolvers, reflection, etc. then there is no static analysis that can tell you the guaranteed correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

A code map might help - have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238403.aspx) article. You need Enterprise for the built in one though. Alternatively, you could try [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MichaelKissBG8.VS10xCodeMAP); I've not used it but it seems to do a similar thing.